# Why doesn't the following embedded 'OnClick' work when id = "pattern" on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

This is probably something simple I'm overlooking but my google-fu isn't turning anything up that could explain the cause. Take the following snippet for example (Ignoring for now that embedded js is generally considered bad practice):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body> 
    <form action="">
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="pattern" value="foobar">
        <input type="button" value="Alert" OnClick="alert(pattern.value);">
      </div>  
    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

The above will print the alert message 'foobar' in IE8 and Firefox 3 but Chrome will print 'undefined'. Changing `pattern` to something else like `pattern_` will print 'foobar' for all three browsers as expected.

Is `pattern` a reserved word or a name used for one of the builtin js libraries? What's the reason for this not working under Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because internally the mentioned browsers attach DOM elements as Objects to the global namespace (`window`). So, an object with `id="xyz"` can also be addressed as `window.xyz` or even as `xyz`. I suppose Chrome doesn't do this.

Also check [my SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here) about this,  especially the selected answer.

[**edit**] after comment: it's Chrome (webkit) related indeed and it may have something to do with what I found [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/html/9780132734653/intelligent-forms/ch03lev1sec3#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAxMzI3MzQ2NTMvMzk=). See also [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs.html) (search the page for 'pattern' it looks like in HTML5 `pattern` is an attribute of `input`, so I can imagine that interferes with an id having the same name)

Comment: that would not account for the fact that changing the id works

Comment: ok, fair enough, I was just going after what Victor T. said. Thx

Comment: Yep, interesting, and I can't find anything about that. Still, it's not advisable to use global variables like the OP showed in his code, I think.

Comment: @Kooil's explanation seems to be the most plausible, though why would the browser be in quirks mode even though I specified the doctype to be html 4.01? Oddly, this passes w3 validation. I'll probably accept this answer if a better one doesn't come along.

Comment: @Victor T: I don't know either, but it may be a browser issue (there's enough issues to solve @ chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables for access to DOM elements by id. There is `document.getElementById(...)` for that purpose, and even better - a selector function in nearly any js library/framework (e.g. `$('#yourid')` in jQuery, `$('yourid')` in Prototype, etc.). They guarantee you cross-browser support, while globals may vary on each browser.

Comment: +1 for the advice. I would use `getElement(s)*` methods in actual pages of course. Though I'm still curious about this quirk I ran into while I was experimenting.